# Update from client or use Google Storage Trigger?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently uploading images to the Firebase Storage and then updating the Firestore database with the URL that was returned from the Storage:

```swift
func uploadFile(fileName: String, userId: String, completion: @escaping (StorageUploadTask?, FileUploadError?) -> Void) {
    do {
        let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let localFile = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("")
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localFile.path) {
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "image/*"
            imageRef = storageRef.child(userId).child(fileName)
            let uploadTask = imageRef.putFile(from: localFile, metadata: metadata)
            
            completion(uploadTask, nil)
        } else {
            completion(nil, .fileNotAvailable)
        }
    } catch {
        completion(nil, .fileManagerError(error.localizedDescription))
    }
}

uploadFile(fileName: previewData.fileName, userId: self!.userId) {(url, error) in

    db.collection("post").document(documentId).updateData([
        "images": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["\(url)"])
    ], completion: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            self?.alert.showDetail("Error", with: error.localizedDescription, for: self)
        }
    })
}
```

I realized that I could also create a Cloud Storage trigger to update the Firestore instead of making a round trip to the client.  My understanding is that there is a tradeoff in costs incurred between the CPU used for the Cloud Functions and the Firestore usage, but is there a best practice this specific process? I'm using a loop to upload multiple images to the Storage.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to understand its advantages. Cloud Functions is great for triggering Firebase and Google Cloud events. It automatically scales your function and provisions dedicated CPU & Memory for each request, which is perfect for resource intensive tasks.

My answer is that, it all depends on how big your app is and how you wish to scale it. If your app has only a small amount of users, then your code would be fine. But, if your app requires additional scaling design to make room for large amount of invocations, then consider taking advantage of Cloud Functions.

If cost is a concern, then you can prepare by predicting your monthly costs in [GCP Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

---

**Note**: Cloud Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions is a beta feature with some [known limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#limitations_and_guarantees):

- It can take up to 10 seconds for a function to respond to changes in Cloud Firestore.
- Ordering is not guaranteed. Rapid changes can trigger function invocations in an unexpected order.
- Events are delivered at least once, but a single event may result in multiple function invocations. Avoid depending on exactly-once mechanics, and write idempotent functions.
- Cloud Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions is available only for Cloud Firestore in Native mode. It is not available for Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode.